# Evaluate a data variable before a request

Tags: javascript, mootools

Is there a way to evaluate a variable within a "data" option in a Request in the following code:

```
var v_postfield=valueA;
new Request({
var self = this;
    emulation:false,
    url: self.ajaxurl,
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token':rails.csrf.token },
    data: {'task': { v_postfield: self.field.get('value')}},
    evalResponse: true,
    evalScripts: true
}).put();
```

I keep getting:

> Parameters: {"task"=>{"v_postfield"=>"ddd"},
>   "id"=>"4e21c97023525c19730000d3"}

When I just want:

> Parameters: {"task"=>{"valueA"=>"ddd"},
>   "id"=>"4e21c97023525c19730000d3"}

The server is running on rubyonrails but I doubt it is related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right. if I understand your question correctly, you need to pass on dynamic values as object members.

this is down to javascript and the syntactic sugar that allows you to access properties of objects via the . notation:

```
var obj = {
    prop: value
};

obj.prop === value;
```

when you want a dynamic property, you need to use the underlying brackets notation instead (like in arrays):

```
var obj = {}, prop = "foo";
obj[prop] = value;

obj == { foo: value };
```

that's about it.

so:

```
var taskobj = {};
taskobj[v_postfield] = self.field.get('value');
// ...
data: {
    task: taskobj
}
```

Comment: Great thanks, (just in case someone asks, I also added the quotes around the task as in  `'task': taskobj` )